# How to change the alignment of the text in the first line longtable?

Tags: longtable

I have a table:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.13\linewidth}||p{0.35\linewidth}||p{0.45\linewidth}|}

\hline
\textbf{\large Text1} &
\textbf{\large Text2} &
\textbf{\large Text3}\\
\hline
\textbf{\large Text4} &
\textbf{\large Text5} &
\textbf{\large Text6}\\
\hline

\end{longtable}
```

How to change the alignment of the text in the first line longtable?
I want to align Text1, Text2, Text3, for example, center.
Or I can't do in a longtable?

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is exactly the same as `tabular`: since you have `p` columns you can use

```
\centering\arraybackslash\large\textbf{Text1}
```

Comment: Thanks. And if the environment is, for tables that allow you to write all this easier? Those. I want a high-level table and not lose the flexibility of settings.